# Why the listener is displaying always the number of the last iteration?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, templates, addeventlistener

The alert is showing ever the number 10 no matter what number you have clicked.
Maybe this is not the best way to use a addEventListener inside a loop. 
Need some help. Thank you.

```
<table id="tb1"></table>

<template id="tp1">
    <tr>
        <td class="num"></td>
    </tr>
</template>

<script>

    var t = document.getElementById("tp1");
    var tb1 = document.getElementById("tb1");

    for (i=0;i<10;i++){

        var clone = t.content.cloneNode(true);

        clone.querySelector(".num").innerHTML = i;

        var l = clone.querySelector("tr");
        l.id = i;

        clone.getElementById(i).addEventListener("click",function(){
            alert(i);            
        });

        tb1.append(clone);
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `i` variable get the last value of the loop by reference.. In this case 10

You can solve this by using an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) were the function becomes a function expression which is immediately executed. The variable within the expression can not be accessed from outside

Code example:

```js
var t = document.getElementById('tp1');
var tb1 = document.getElementById('tb1');

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var clone = t.content.cloneNode(true);
  clone.querySelector('.num').innerHTML = i;
  var l = clone.querySelector('tr');
  l.id = i;
  (function (i) {
    clone.getElementById(i).addEventListener('click', function () {
      console.log(i);
    });
  })(i);
  tb1.append(clone);
}
```

```html
<table id="tb1"></table>

<template id="tp1">
    <tr>
        <td class="num"></td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Note: I have replaced the use of `alert()` by `console.log()` just for convenience

Comment: I thought that the addEventListener was already being executed immediately. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 3):

This is a classic [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) mistake.

replace

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++)
```

by

```
for (let i=0;i<10;i++)
```

Comment: Worked as weel as the Yosvel solution.

Comment: But I´m concerned about not supporting this solution on mobile browser. https://caniuse.com/#search=let

Comment: The example involves a closure, but it is not a closure mistake. It is a scope mistake. You need to create a new scope => using let is a good solution if ES6/ES2015 is an option. Using an IIFE will work with ES5 and older browsers.